# Is there a way to login a cognito user which is federated by open id connect in Android?

Tags: android, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, aws-userpools

I'm attempting to use an external OAuth2 login provider (like Auth0) through Cognito User Pools.

This is using the flow described here:

[image: Social authentication through user pools image]
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-social-idp.html

I am opening a webview in the app and calling the user pool's  login page, which in turn displays the external provider's login page.

When the call returns, it creates a new user and session in user pools, and the user pool page calls back to the app with an access code.

I exchange the access code for an identity token, access token and refresh token.

Is there a way to initialize a CognitoUser with just refresh, access and id tokens for the AWS mobile SDK on Android? It seems like I need to use a CredentialsProvider to access AWS services, and a CognitoUser to perform actions like logging out, refreshing token and things like that.

Cognito User Pool CognitoUsers seem to only be initialised with username and password.

Comment: Andy - did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @toddg At the time of asking there was no way to achieve this, the Amazon team said it would be 6 months to a year before support was added. It's worth checking again.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it’s still not supported 